# Issue with BeautifulSoup and printing a string from findAll function

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the thread titles from /r/Askreddit. The code below returns None instead of the thread title.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2, json

site='http://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/'

soup=BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(site))

questions=soup.findAll('p',{"class":"title"})


for i in questions:
        print i.string
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

The title is in the `string` attribute of the `a` tag, not the `p` tag.
Also, notice the space after `title`:

```
questions=soup.findAll('a',{"class":"title "})
```

---

The above was found by looking at this HTML snippet:

```
<p class="title"><a class="title " href="http://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/l5157/whats_the_best_face_you_can_pull_before_and_after/">What's the best face you can pull? Before and after please.</a> <span class="domain">(<a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/">self.AskReddit</a>)</span></p>
```